# Ruby: which method to use for array of hashes to get a string with all hash values?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

i have an array

```
[{name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"ganesh"}]
```

i want to create a method that return output as

```
"vivek,ramesh,suresh and ganesh".
```

if there are only two hashs like

```
[{name: "vivek"},{name: "ramesh"}]
```

output should be

```
"vivek and ramesh"
```

if names are more than 5 output should be "vivek, ramesh, suresh , nilash,ganesh etc .."

```
arr=[{name: 'vivek'},{name: 'Ganesh'},{name: 'Suresh'},{name: 'Ramesh'},{name: 'Bavesh'}]#,{name: 'Mukesh'}]
a = arr.size

case a 

when 1 
  puts arr[0][:name]


when 2 
  puts arr[0][:name]+" and "+arr[1][:name]



when 3..5
  ar = []
  i=0
  while i<arr.size-2
    ar << arr[i]
    i += 1
  end

ar.each{|hash| printf "#{hash[:name]}"+","}

printf "#{arr[-2][:name]} and #{arr[-1][:name]}."

puts ""


when 6..100
  ar = []
  i=0
  while i<4
    ar << arr[i]
    i += 1
  end

ar.each{|hash| printf "#{hash[:name]}"+","}

printf "#{arr[4][:name]}  etc..."

puts ""

else 
  puts "Error"
end
```

i did like this..but i know there should be a better way to do this with suitable methods can anybody help ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def names_to_sentence(array)
  names = array.map { |hash| hash[:name] }

  case names.length
  when (0..1)
    names.first.to_s
  when (2..5)
    "#{names[0...-1].join(', ')} and #{names[-1]}"
  else
    "#{names[0..4].join(', ')} etc"
  end
end

names_to_sentence([{name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"nilash"},{name:"ganesh"},{name: "foobar"}])
#=> "vivek, ramesh, suresh, nilash, ganesh etc"
names_to_sentence([{name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"ganesh"}])
#=> "vivek, ramesh, suresh and ganesh"
names_to_sentence([{name: "vivek"},{name: "ramesh"}])
#=> "vivek and ramesh"
names_to_sentence([{name: "vivek"}])    
#=> "vivek"
names_to_sentence([])    
#=> ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(arr)
  case arr.size
  when 0 then ""
  when 1 then arr.first[:name]
  else    
    *first, last = arr.map { |h| h[:name] }
    first.join(', ') << (arr.size <= 5 ? " and #{last}" : ", #{last} ..etc")
  end
end

arr = []
convert arr  #=> "" 

arr = [{name: "vivek"}]
convert arr  #=> "vivek" 

arr = [{name: "vivek"}, {name:"ramesh"}]
convert arr  #=> "vivek and ramesh" 

arr = [{name: "vivek"}, {name:"ramesh"}, {name: "suresh"}]
convert arr  #=> "vivek, ramesh and suresh" 

arr = [{name: "vivek"}, {name:"ramesh"}, {name: "suresh"}, {name:"ganesh"}]
convert arr  #=> "vivek, ramesh, suresh and ganesh" 

arr = [{name: "vivek"}, {name:"ramesh"}, {name: "suresh"}, {name:"ganesh"},
       {name: "dog"}, {name: "cat"}]
convert arr  #=> "vivek, ramesh, suresh, ganesh, cat, dog ..etc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for 0, 1, 2 and 2+ names:

```
arr = [{name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"ganesh"}]
names = arr.map { |h| h[:name] }
str = [names.length>1 ? names[0..-2].join(", ") : nil, 
       names[-1]].compact.join(" and ")
```

Saw the "more than 5" case too late - left as an excercise to yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
λ = ->(input) do
  output = input.flat_map(&:values)
  if output.size > 5
    output.take(5).join(', ') << ' etc.'
  else
    [output.pop, output.join(', ')].reverse.join(' and ')
  end
end

λ.([{name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"ganesh"}])
#⇒ "vivek, ramesh, suresh and ganesh"

λ.([{name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"}])
#⇒ "vivek and ramesh"

input = [
  {name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"ganesh"},
  {name: "vivek"},{name:"ramesh"},{name: "suresh"},{name:"ganesh"}
]
λ.(input)
#⇒ "vivek, ramesh, suresh, ganesh, vivek etc."
```